# System test fails after adding bootstrap theme via yarn

Tags: node-modules, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-themes

I have simple system test that was initially passing:

```rb
require 'application_system_test_case'

class UserVisitHomePageTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'User should see home page' do
    visit root_path

    assert_css 'h1', text: 'Home'
  end
end
```

Then, I install [material-dashboard](https://yarn.pm/material-dashboard) via yarn, and added this line in `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import '~material-dashboard/assets/scss/material-dashboard';
```

I adjust my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as per material-dashboard [documentation](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/docs/2.0/getting-started/introduction.html).

All went working, the theme has been applied, but my system test now fails:

```
UserVisitHomePageTest#test_User_should_see_home_page:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/assets/css/material-dashboard.css"
```

1. Why the test is searching for that route `/assets/css/material-dashboard.css`?
2. How could I make it pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make the system test pass by updating my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, removing (not including) those CSS link tags and JS script tags that reference the asset files of the material dashboard.